# My apps will not open

Tags: boot, bios

Ok so I fixed the fsck/dev2 I added some wording to the boot in terminal. For some reason my apps won't open, my background can't be changed, I can't even update the time. I also removed a profile someone help! I am a fairly new user any tips?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].